# i want to include node scheduling code in my sails

Tags: cron, sails.js

i want to include node scheduling code in my sails , but i don't know where i put the code in my sails . 
 But i tried to put the code in my config/bootstrap.js .but it doesn't run . code is

```
sails.on('lifted', function() {
var schedule = require('node-schedule');

                 var j = schedule.scheduleJob({hour: 0, minute: 1, dayOfWeek: 0}, function(){


                            console.log('Time for tea!');
                            });

  });
```

I want to know , where i put this code. Main conditions is , that file execute every time when my sails server lift.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry if it doesn't format the code since I am on my tablet. This was surprisingly easy. I used node-cron and put the following code in my services folder as a file called Cron.js

I do not believe I had to place any code anywhere else to start the job.

```
/*
https://github.com/ncb000gt/node-cron
Read up on cron patterns here.  http://crontab.org/


When specifying your cron values you'll need to make sure that your values fall within the ranges. For instance, some cron's use a 0-7 range for the day of week where both 0 and 7 represent Sunday. We do not.

Seconds: 0-59
Minutes: 0-59
Hours: 0-23
Day of Month: 1-31
Months: 0-11
Day of Week: 0-6



How to check if a cron pattern is valid:
    try {
        new CronJob('invalid cron pattern', function() {
            console.log('this should not be printed');
        })
    } catch(ex) {
        console.log("cron pattern not valid");
    }

constructor(cronTime, onTick, onComplete, start, timezone, context) - Of note, the first parameter here can be a JSON object that has the below names and associated types (see examples above).
cronTime - [REQUIRED] - The time to fire off your job. This can be in the form of cron syntax or a JS Date object.
onTick - [REQUIRED] - The function to fire at the specified time.
onComplete - [OPTIONAL] - A function that will fire when the job is complete, when it is stopped.
start - [OPTIONAL] - Specifies whether to start the job just before exiting the constructor. By default this is set to false. If left at default you will need to call job.start() in order to start the job (assuming job is the variable you set the cronjob to).
timeZone - [OPTIONAL] - Specify the timezone for the execution. This will modify the actual time relative to your timezone.
context - [OPTIONAL] - The context within which to execute the onTick method. This defaults to the cronjob itself allowing you to call this.stop(). However, if you change this you'll have access to the functions and values within your context object.
start - Runs your job.
stop - Stops your job.

*/

var CronJob = require('cron').CronJob;
var job = new CronJob({
  cronTime: '00 30 11 * * 1-5',
  onTick: function() {
    // Runs every weekday (Monday through Friday)
    // at 11:30:00 AM. It does not run on Saturday
    // or Sunday.
  },
  start: false,
  timeZone: "America/Los_Angeles"
});
job.start()
```

;

Answer (score 0):

As you rightly said config/bootstrap.js is one place where you can have your Job schedulers,

The below cron will execute at 00 hrs 00 mins 00 secs daily
From the left

1. The first 00 is seconds can hold values (00-59)
2. The second 00 is minutes can hold values (00-59)
3. The third 00 is hours can hold values (00-23)
4. The fourth position * is Day can hold values (00-30)
5. The fifth position * is Month can hold values (00-11)
6. The sixth position * is the Day of Week can hold values (0-6)

   ```
   module.exports.bootstrap = function (cb) {
     try {
       var CronJob = require('cron').CronJob;
       new CronJob('00 00 00 * * *', function() {
         sails.controllers.controllerName.functionName(sails.request, sails.response, sails.next, function(err,data){
           console.log(err,"err");
         });
       }, null, true);
     } 
     catch(ex) {
       console.log("cron pattern not valid");
     } 
     cb();
   };
   ```

Note: The function which you are using should not have any res.json or res.something